# Docker run "invalid reference format"

Tags: python, docker

I have seen multiple similar questions, but none of them helped.
I try to run
 `docker run —name my_app -it —rm -v "$(pwd):/service" nuadu_app python run_script/hello_world.py` and it fails `docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.`
I have spent quite a sometime to understand what is going wrong here and i cant find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about your command, try to use:

```
docker run --name my_app -it --rm -v "$(pwd):/service" nuadu_app python run_script/hello_world.py
```

I guess the problem was that you have copied the command from a file, an environment or an IDE that that didn't have the same encoding as the terminal from which you executed `docker run ...`.

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: yeap it stil lthe same :/

Comment: there were special characters in your command, copy and use the one I put in my answer.

Comment: Could you please point out what were the characters for the future reference ? That did indeed work, but i still have no idea what exactly was wrong ;p (apart from --rm / --name)

Comment: I guess the probleme was that you have copied the command from a file, an environment or an IDE that that didn't have the same encoding as the terminal from which you executed `docker run ...`.